# SQL, way to make the statement shorter?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am an new IT student and i have some school examples.

Here I have a SQL statement witch is very long and slow to load.
Does someone here know how to make this one smaller?
Using mysql

```
SELECT genre, titel, speelduur
FROM film
    WHERE speelduur =
    (SELECT MAX(speelduur)
     FROM film
     WHERE genre ='Actie')
AND genre = 'Actie'
OR speelduur =
    (SELECT MAX(speelduur)
     FROM film
     WHERE genre ='Avontuur')
AND genre = 'Avontuur'
OR speelduur =
    (SELECT MAX(speelduur)
     FROM film
     WHERE genre ='Comedie')
AND genre = 'Comedie'
OR speelduur =
    (SELECT MAX(speelduur)
     FROM film
     WHERE genre ='Dans')
AND genre = 'Dans'
OR speelduur =
    (SELECT MAX(speelduur)
     FROM film
     WHERE genre ='Drama')
AND genre = 'Drama'
OR speelduur =
    (SELECT MAX(speelduur)
     FROM film
     WHERE genre ='Epos')
AND genre = 'Epos'
OR speelduur =
    (SELECT MAX(speelduur)
     FROM film
     WHERE genre ='Fantasie')
AND genre = 'Fantasie'
OR speelduur =
    (SELECT MAX(speelduur)
     FROM film
     WHERE genre ='Historisch')
AND genre = 'Historisch'
OR speelduur =
    (SELECT MAX(speelduur)
     FROM film
     WHERE genre ='Horror')
AND genre = 'Misdaad'
OR speelduur =
    (SELECT MAX(speelduur)
     FROM film
     WHERE genre ='Musical')
AND genre = 'Musical'
OR speelduur =
    (SELECT MAX(speelduur)
     FROM film
     WHERE genre ='Mysterie')
AND genre = 'Mysterie'
OR speelduur =
    (SELECT MAX(speelduur)
     FROM film
     WHERE genre ='Oorlog')
AND genre = 'Oorlog'
OR speelduur =
    (SELECT MAX(speelduur)
     FROM film
     WHERE genre ='Rampen')
AND genre = 'Rampen'
OR speelduur =
    (SELECT MAX(speelduur)
     FROM film
     WHERE genre ='Religieus')
AND genre = 'Religieus'
OR speelduur =
    (SELECT MAX(speelduur)
     FROM film
     WHERE genre ='Romantiek')
AND genre = 'Romantiek'
OR speelduur =
    (SELECT MAX(speelduur)
     FROM film
     WHERE genre ='Science Fiction')
AND genre = 'Science Fiction'
```

You see my problem right?:P

Answer (score 0):

```
select  f.genre,
        f.title,
        f.speeldur
from    film f
  join (
        select      genre,
                    max(speelduur) as max_speelduur_for_genre
        from        film
        group by    genre
       ) v
    on f.genre = v.genre
   and f.speeldur = v.max_speelduur_for_genre
```

Comment: The original query returned `MAX(speelduur)` for genre `'Horror'`, then matched that to rows with genre `'Misdaad'`.

Comment: @spencer7593 I suspect that was a typo if the OP indicates that it's working. I'm not sure why you took the time to downvote this answer and post the same query, with that one difference.

Comment: @BrianDeMilia: I didn't downvote your answer. As to my answer, yes, I also provided an answer to the question that includes an explanation of a possible approach to a query, along with an example query. As far as my query having "one difference", I think I was working on an answer at the same time as you were. (And, there's actually a couple of differences.) You posted your answer first, so you "won". (Perhaps I should model my answer after yours, and remove everything except for the SQL text.)

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** You seem my problem, right?

**A:** Yes, we see the problem.

As one possible approach to both shortening the query, and improving performance, we could use an inline view query to return the `MAX(speeldur)` for the listed genres. The results from that query get materialized into a temporary table, which MySQL refers to as a "derived table". The outer query then performs  a JOIN operation between the "derived table" and the `film` table, to get the related rows from `film`.

We note, according to the original query that we need to get the `MAX(speeldur)` for 'Horror' genre, but then match that to `speelduur` for rows that have 'Misdaad' genre. (A bit curious that needs to be done, but we can handle that in the JOIN predicate, no problem.)

If the intent is to get "all" genre, we could omit the predicate `WHERE g.genre IN (list)` from the view query. Then we'd get all possible values of `genre` returned.

As an example of this approach:

```
SELECT f.genre
     , f.titel
     , f.speelduur
  FROM film f
  JOIN ( SELECT g.genre
              , MAX(g.speelduur) AS max_speelduur
           FROM film g
          WHERE g.genre IN ('Actie','Avontuur','Comedie','Dans','Drama'
                           ,'Epos','Fantasie','Historisch','Horror'
                           ,'Musical','Mysterie','Oorlog','Rampen'
                           ,'Religieus','Romantiek','Science Fiction')
          GROUP BY g.genre
       ) m
  JOIN film f
    ON f.genre = IF(m.genre='Horror','Misdaad',m.genre)
   AND f.speelduur = m.max_speelduur
```

For best performance, we want to have suitable indexes available. For this query, we'd expect this to be sufficient:

```
... ON film (genre, speelduur)
```

As an alternative, we could instead define an index like this:

```
... ON film (genre, speelduur, film)
```

since that will be a "covering index" for the outer query.

Comment: If we don't want to swap the genre `'Misdaad'` for `'Horror'` genre (like was shown in the original query), then we could remove the `IF()` expression in the join predicate, and replace it with just `m.genre`.

Answer (score 0):

This works in MySql 5.5

```
 SELECT MAX(speelduur), genre
 FROM film
 where genre in ('Actie','Comedie','Dans')
 group by genre desc
```

Add more genres as appropriate.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6d7b/4